# Postman: Extract data from javascript and HTML response into a JSON object

Tags: javascript, html, json, postman, cheerio

I'm using Postman and Cheerio to scrape data from an HTML response. In the example below, I am trying to pull the data in `DDC.dataLayer['b']` (which is found in a `<script>` tag) into a JSON object.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(f1){
...
};
DDC.dataLayer['a'] = {
...
};
DDC.dataLayer['b'] = [{
"b1": "b1",
"b2": "b2",
"b3": {"b31":"01","b32":"name"}
}];
DDC.dataLayer.c = {
aa: [],
bb: [],
cc: []
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I managed to pull all the text in between the script tags into a variable, however, when I try to use JSON.parse on it, I get an error because of the function f1. How would I pull just `DDC.dataLayer['b']` into a JSON object in Postman?

Thanks!

Comment: Ddc.datalayer is an identifier inside the function or outside it ?  Why can't you simply use regular expression?

Comment: It's an identifier outside the function. Alas I'm not an expert with regular expressions and also not sure how one would use it in Postman.

Answer (score 1):

I created an API showing the code to extract the JSON:

API:
https://wirespec.dev/Wirespec/projects/apis/Stackoverflow/apis/extractJSONFromHTML

Response:
https://api.wirespec.dev/wirespec/stackoverflow/extractjsonfromhtml

Javascript Hook used by Wirespec:
https://gist.github.com/Wirespec/fa305719276d9e9276debce231b43bd3

Comment: This kind of works, thanks. You made some assumptions that are true in the html example I give, but may not be true in real HTML. eg: there are multiple occurrences of "}];" and it is not always formatted the same (ie: "}];" may not always be together on the same line). This may differ from time to time depending on the rest of the info on the site, so while using substrings may work, it's rather brittle.

Answer (score 0):

```
html.match(/DDC.dataLayer\['b'\] = (\[.*?\])/s)[1]
```

The ? makes it non-greedy

Answer (score 0):

```
// find the start of the varaible you want 
start = a.indexOf("DDC.dataLayer['b'] =")+"DDC.dataLayer['b'] =".length;

//find the end using ';'
stop = a.indexOf(";",a.indexOf("DDC.dataLayer['b']"))

console.log(start,stop)

// find the substring and parse it
var res = a.substring(start,stop)

console.log(JSON.parse(res))
```

add this to your test script